# Two implementations of reboot?

Tags: linux, init.d, reboot

Why do there seem to be two implementations of reboot on my linux system?

```
# find . -name "reboot"
./etc/init.d/reboot
./sbin/reboot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/sbin/reboot is the actual binary that actually is a symbolic link to the halt daemon

```
$ls -la /sbin/reboot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr  6  2015 /sbin/reboot -> halt
```

The halt binary is coded in such a way that the behaviour differs when called as halt or when called as reboot from the command line.

/etc/init.d/reboot is actually a script invoked in runlevel 6 when shutting down, by:

```
/etc/init.d/rc6.d/K10reboot
```

As you can see:

```
$ ls -la /etc/rc6.d/K10reboot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Nov 14 18:19 /etc/rc6.d/K10reboot -> ../init.d/reboot
```

The actual /etc/init.d/reboot when invoked with the option stop, as it happens with the above mentioned Kxx symlink calls the reboot binary as

```
reboot -d -f -i
```

From "man reboot"

```
-d     Don't write the wtmp record.
-i     Shut down all network interfaces just before halt or reboot.
-f     Force halt or reboot, don't call shutdown(8).
```

As for the comment about Kxxx scripts, and runlevel 6, they are part of Sys V init scripts.

Please see an explanation here:

http://www.linuxvoodoo.com/resources/howtos/sysvinit

Comment: separate question: i can't find documentation on those `-d` and `-i` flags.  http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot

Comment: run the command "man reboot". I expanded the answer.